# React Web App File Saving (Suggestions)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I'm building a React web app that takes in torrent pieces and these have to be temporarily stored somewhere for a web player to then view them.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can temporarily store this data to be used later for the streaming aspect of the process?

At the moment, I have pieces that are being stored in an array in a `var`, but I'm unsure if I should store this somewhere before using the data.

I know JavaScript inherently doesn't allow this sort of functionality for security reasons, but I would like to somehow store the files until they get disposed of on user exit or something.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should choose firebase for this purpose. It is secure, user friendly and lightweight web and mobile apps development program.

Since you want to store your data temporarily, then it will be best place to choose.

I myself used it so many times to store my data for long and short period. The thing I like most about it, is that you don't even need any server side scripting to save data in firebase Database. React provide its package manager that you can use to create and store data. So you can do this using client side language only.

Firebase Authentication helps you to secure data from other user's access. You can create your own login details for protection.

Firebase Storage helps you to put your files under one folder.

Firebase Database can store the links of your files so when user wants to access it in future they can click that link.

There are many other benefits of using firebase, you will know when you use it. If you still have difficulty to use it let me help you with that.

Thanks